# C++ Simple Login Project

Tags: c++

I tried making a simple login authentication program in C++. I wanted help on how to make a dictionary of username and passwords so as to authenticate login info. For the simple project I just assigned a login string with a string and password too and checked the input of user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string username = "cool";
    string password = "lol";
    string user;
    string pass;
    cout << "Hello, Welcome to the App Login!" << std::endl;
    cout << "Enter Your username: ";
    cin >> user;
    if (user == username){
        cout << "Enter password: " << endl;
        cin >> pass;
        if (pass == password){
            cout << "Successful Login!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect Password!" << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect Username!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ron, go ahead and hash the password and then store the hash along with the user name. Never store plain-text passwords. To check, read the user supplied password and hash it and compare with the saved hash. That way the plain password is never stored. (also, don't post pictures of text in your question, copy/paste the text indented by 4-spaces to format correctly, or include `\`\`\`` above and below the text to avoid the indention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to create your dictionary and use map's [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) method to check if the key is present in map or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // create your dictonary
    map<string, string>dict = { {"john", "123"} };
    string username, password;
    cout<<"Enter username: "<<endl;
    cin>>username;
    cout<<"Enter password: "<<endl;
    cin>>password;
    // Check if provided username and password matches with the one is dictonary
    if(dict.find(username) != dict.end() && dict[username] == password) {
        cout<<"Login Successfully!";
    } else {
        cout<<"Invalid Credentials";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/efzUvv)

Comment: Small improvement: Cache the result of `dict.find(username)` so that you don't have to look it up again with `dict[username]`. Instead you can `found->second == password;`

Comment: You may consider using [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) in this case since sorting the keys using `std::map` will just put unnecessary overhead which could increase as one goes on adding more "records" in the "dictionary".